# Other evaluation systems than exams

Tags: university, exams, education

I live in a country where the quality of education is poor. 
The primary goal seems only to be to teach us how to pass exams and not to learn the material for knowledge sake. It appears that their sole focus is for us to score well on tests so that we can get into a better college an maybe get a good job.

It is only about exams and I feel like I am being deprived of an education.

As I am not familiar with other education systems, I would like to know if there are education system where there are evaluation systems other than exams or where there is less of an emphasis on teaching to the exam?

Are there systems that evaluate a student's performance based on writing papers of doing projects?

Comment: I've avoided them like the plague as I loathed writing then, but some classes expect a [term paper](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_paper) that makes up a large part (probably sometimes all) of your grade.  There are also [term projects](http://www.mbio.ncsu.edu/mb452/project/project.html). Besides, what do you mean when you say "at the first place?"

Comment: Even in many countries where the education system is considered good, there's a huge overemphasis on teaching to tests and not to learning (e.g, US, Japan, etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Gnometorule mentions in the comments, you'll find a variety of other types of assessments.

The three most common ones for end-of-course assessment are the exam, the project, and the paper, but they definitely aren't the only things that can be used to determine a grade.

In literature classes, and I'd imagine the majority of humanities classes, papers are a more common form of assessment.  Even exams, when given, are more paper-like being in essay format.  In most math courses, on the other hand, you'll tend to find exams are more common.  In computer science courses or the visual arts, projects are probably more likely the substantial source of grades.

It's also not uncommon, at least in the US, to find other elements of courses counting for part of the final grade.  Participation can be an important element of discussion classes, or classes where interaction with other students is very important such as in music or theatre courses (and those may also have a performance/recital as part of the grade, though that may be considered a test of sorts).  Homework may also be counted as a portion of the grade.  Portfolios, which can be a sort of mix of hybrid of homework and/or smaller projects, are also relatively common.